# SAS lowercase SHA256 string

Tags: sas, sha

Currently testing a SHA256 function in order to prepare a variable for use in another application.

The user has requested the SHA256 result be in lower case. I created a quick record in order to make sure I can convert the string-

```
data have;
input first $ last $ dob $ 10. sex $;
cards;
test person 1955-07-31 1
;
run;
```

Seems it will not allow a lower case string once passed through the SHA function.

Is there a workaround for this? The below attempt did not yield desirable results.

```
data have2;
set have;
source = catt(first,last,dob,sex);
encryp = lowcase(sha256(source));
format encryp $hex64.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will do it using a `put` statement with the format inside:

```
data have2;
set have;
encryp = lowcase(put(sha256(catt(first,last,dob,sex)),$hex64.));
run;
```

It will show an entirely different encryption code compared to your method but it remains consistent.

```
data have;
input first $ last $ dob $ 10. sex $;
cards;
test person 1955-07-31 1
test person 1955-07-31 1
test2 person 1977-08-11 2
test3 person 1945-12-22 1
;
run;

data have2;
set have;
new_encryp = lowcase(put(sha256(catt(first,last,dob,sex)),hex64.)); /* new method */
encryp = lowcase(sha256(catt(first,last,dob,sex))); /* what you tried */
format encryp $hex64.;
run;

/* output */
first   last    dob         sex new_encryp                                                          encryp
test    person  7/31/1955   1   038a855a47f40edf54094adc4366e3e79c1a931346d7968e96d2cb930b01e7bc    039A857A67F40EDF74096AFC6366E3E79C1A931366D7969E96F2EB930B01E7BC
test    person  7/31/1955   1   038a855a47f40edf54094adc4366e3e79c1a931346d7968e96d2cb930b01e7bc    039A857A67F40EDF74096AFC6366E3E79C1A931366D7969E96F2EB930B01E7BC
test2   person  8/11/1977   2   1117ab614f48a7edfbe9d615f12acad9d564b457b0f31bb2619f7eb9b10f1e58    1117AB616F68A7EDFBE9F615F12AEAF9F564B477B0F31BB261FF7EB9B10F1E78
test3   person  12/22/1945  1   d1cb00ebe044c0553039f99592dc7bd4804eac2c13da8208fd82459c3a37efd1    F1EB00EBE064E0753039F99592FC7BF4806EAC2C13FA8208FD82659C3A37EFF1
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but answers like this aren't very useful as they don't explain _why_ this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with the `sha256` function, but with the `$HEX64` format.

When you used `lowcase` you actually do some harm to the `SHA256` result: you're not altering the hexadecimal representation, but you're actually altering the characters themselves, which means your result isn't accurate - and then you're displaying them with `$HEX64.` which will always show capital letters for the hexadecimal characters.

What instead you want, presumably, is to store the lower case version of the `$HEX64.` format.  You can do that with `put`:

```
data want;
  set have;
  source = catt(first,last,dob,sex);
  encryp = sha256(source);
  lower  = lowcase(put(encryp,$HEX64.));
run;
```

Note what `encryp` looks like - something totally different, and probably not particularly useful.  You can of course skip that step if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
*convert case;

%let txt="SEQ_CLAIM_ID, SEQ_MEMB_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE";

%macro lower_case(txt);
    data;
        text=lowcase(&txt);
    run;
%mend;

%lower_case(&txt);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: My SAS macro accepts an uppercase text string and converts it to a lowercase text string within a dataset table.So, if your goal is to change the case of a text string this should help.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm not sure why a macro would be necessary, when you could just call the `lowcase` function and `put` within the data step, as the solutions provided.

Comment: @SMW I agree, but the macro allows you the freedom of choosing any text string for conversion without limiting to specific variables.